# Swift Newbie Basic Function

Tags: swift

```
func myEarnings(net: Double) -> Double {
    let tax: Double = net * 0.3
    return net - tax
}

myEarnings(net: 710.45)
```

I cant get an output from my code. I don’t understand why. No bugs on playground.

Comment: You meant: `let result = myEarnings(net: 710.45); print("result: \(result)")`?

Comment: You need to hold the return value as it's currently on the fly

Comment: Your function returns some value. Try to print or store that value instead just calling the function. Code looks fine though.

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    let value = myEarnings(net: 710.45) //store the value return by function
    print("value",value)
    }
    
    func myEarnings(net: Double) -> Double {
        let tax: Double = net * 0.3
        return net - tax
    }

Comment: Looks like you're using a playground, so: don't forget to open the "Debug area", this is were messages are printed. If you're not using `print` at all then you can still see a preview next to the code. Open all view panes in the playground.

Comment: Are you using this function in a app you're trying to make?

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone. I’ve learned a lot from your comments. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    let value = myEarnings(net: 710.45) //store the value return by function
    print("value",value)
    }

    func myEarnings(net: Double) -> Double {
        let tax: Double = net * 0.3
        return net - tax
    }
```

Comment: how do you know that this is even inside a view controller?

Comment: I don't know where it is, maybe he is using the playground, but the function and function call remain the same so no worries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to see what the function will return use

`print(myEarnings(net: 710.45))`